# Windows host name resolution stopped working

Tags: linux, networking, windows, dns

I followed instruction on the web to get my Linux laptop to resolve Windows 7 host name:

`sudo apt install winbind libnss-winbind`
`sudo nano /etc/nsswitch.conf`
{ updated the "hosts:" line to read:
`"hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns wins mdns4"` }

That worked for a few hours, but has now stopped working.  I verified the packages are still installed and the edit to `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is still there.

I can ping the host in question by its IP address.

I don't know everything I did in those few hours, but I do know I rebooted the laptop a few times.

Comment: *That worked for a few hours...* - hmmm, if you can't remember what you did, then we'll be hard-pressed to troubleshoot this.

Comment: You didn't change anything on the Windows machine? Whether or not a Windows machine responds to a mDNS query depends on the network type: public, private or domain. The type can't be public, IIRC.

Comment: Ignore my comment about not making changes on the Linux laptop.  I have reinstalled Pop_OS 20.4 from scratch and this is the first change I am making to that fresh install.  Same symptom.  I have not made any changes to the Windows box.

I can run the following command after a reboot and the windows name starts resolving; "/etc/init.d/winbind reload".  I haven't seen anything in my reading on this that something needs changed in the login scripts.  Does this info help as to what needs done?  Do I need to put this command or one like it in the .profile?

Comment: After reboot, wait 3-4 minutes. For some reason, host name resolution take time...

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I ended up installing samba (sudo apt install samba) and that seems to now allow winbind to start on boot.

In my case my linux is using systemd and the winbind.service file showed a dependency (After=) on nmbd.service, which is a part of Samba.  I tried removing that one dependency, but that did not help. So, there is some greater intertwining of winbind and samba at startup, although the Samba components don't seem needed to execute winbind.

I probably would have needed to install Samba eventually anyway.